# Android Studio downloads Gradle everytime I create new project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I don't know why my Android Studio performs this way but whenever I create a new project, or sometimes even when I open an existing one, it starts downloading Gradle. I have the version which the project requires but still it downloads Gradle. Currently I am using Gradle 8.0, with plugin version 8.0.1. I sometimes try deleting the .gradle folder but this doesn't works. Also my GRADLE_USER_HOME was set to:

> C:\Users$USER_NAME$.gradle/wrapper\dists\gradle-7.1-bin\4pslxx9lrxt5svtz5wbnb6tkz\gradle-7.1\bin\wrapper\dists\gradle-8.0-bin\ca5e32bp14vu59qr306oxotwh

But I have currently changed it to:

> C:\Users$USER_NAME$.gradle/

*Please help me out*